# Flutter, The method 'containsKey' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
documentSnapshot.data().containsKey("fieldName")
```

I updated Flutter from 2.23 to 2.8

and suddenly red line occurs

and the error message is

```
The method 'containsKey' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
```

There is a red line under containsKey How to solve this?

Comment: Are you try `snapshot.docs.contains('element');`

Comment: What type of object is your `documentSnapshot.data()`?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, convert to the type of the data works.

```
 final docData = docSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
 if (docSnapshot.exists && !docData.containsKey('labels')) {
     return;
 }
```